# Rspec for ssh connection

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am trying to write rspec to test ssh connection. In my spec file even though I have enetered incorrect server password it still says `0 examples, 0 failures`. Can someone exmplain me why am I seeing that whereas I am expected to see at least one failure message.

Below is the piece of code of my `ssh_host.rb` and `ssh_host_spec.rb files`.

```
require "java"
require "highline/import"
require 'open-uri'
require 'socket'
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/ssh'
require 'stringio'
require 'net/scp'
require 'colorize'

module SshMod

class SshHost 

    attr_accessor :hostname, :username, :password

    def initialize(host, user, password)
            @hostname = host
            @username = user
            @password = password

            @ssh = Net::SSH.start(@hostname, @username, :password => @password)
            puts "\t Connection established for #{@hostname}...".blue
    end
end
end
```

Rspec Class:

```
#!/usr/bin/env rspec

require 'spec_helper'
require 'ssh_host.rb'

describe SshMod::SshHost do
  before :each do
      @ssh = SshMod::SshHost.new "servername", "user", "wrong_password"

  end
end

describe "#new" do
  it "takes three parameters and returns sshhostobject" do
        @ssh.should_be_an_instance_of SshHost 

  end
end

ssh_mock = double()


expect(SSH).to receive(:start).and_return(ssh_mock)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of things wrong with your spec file. your test for `new` should be within the context of your `SshMod::SshHost` describe otherwise it doesn't have access to the ssh instance variable. Also, your code should throw some errors because `except` isn't defined in Kernel it's within the context of an Rspec object. You most likely want to put it in your `before`.

Regarding your requires in your ruby class, I'd get rid of everything that you don't need (for example, why the explicit inclusion of socket when using net-ssh?).

I believe however, that you're running into the issue where no tests are running most likely due to your project structure (but that's only a guess since you haven't listed it). Rspec by default looks for spec files listed under `spec/**/*_spec.rb` which you can override with the `--pattern` flag. See `rspec --help` for more info.

Here's a working example of your code with a bunch of things cleaned up. I put the source of your code in `lib` assuming you're making something like a gem.

---

Gemfile:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "colorize"
gem "rspec"
gem "net-ssh"
```

lib/ssh_host.rb

```
require 'net/ssh'
require 'colorize'

module SshMod
  class SshHost
    attr_accessor :hostname, :username, :password

    def initialize(host, user, password)
      @hostname = host
      @username = user
      @password = password

      @ssh = Net::SSH.start(@hostname, @username, password: @password)
      puts "\t Connection established for #{@hostname}...".blue
    end
  end
end
```

spec/spec_helper.rb

```
$:.unshift File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'lib')
require 'rspec'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end
end
```

spec/ssh_host_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

require 'ssh_host'

describe SshMod::SshHost do
  let (:ssh) { SshMod::SshHost.new "servername", "user", "wrong_password" }
  before :each do
    allow(Net::SSH).to receive(:start).and_return(double("connection"))
  end

  describe "#new" do
    it "takes three parameters and returns sshhostobject" do
      expect(ssh).to be_a SshMod::SshHost
    end
  end
end
```